# How to delete all log data from ElasticSearch using curl?

Tags: ubuntu, curl, elasticsearch

I want to delete all log data from elasticsearch node. I installed ElasticSearch on ubuntu on a Vmware workstation and nothing else. but size of vmware is growing every day. I don't know if reason of this size growing is because of elasticsearch log operation or not? if yes how can i delete all logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure the issue is with the log files.

```
du -sch /var/log/elasticsearch
```

The above command would be a good place to start with.
Next , make sure the logs are in control.
/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml file has the config for logging.

```
 file:
    type: rollingFile
    file: ${path.logs}/${cluster.name}.log
    maxFileSize: 200000
    maxBackupIndex: 10
    layout:
      type: pattern
      conversionPattern: "[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c] %m%n"
```

The above configuration with maxFileSize and maxBackupIndex should keep a check on this folder size. Decrease the file size if you cant afford it.

If you want to disable logging , change this line in logging.yml

```
rootLogger: ${es.logger.level}, console, file
```

to

```
rootLogger: ${es.logger.level}, console
```

Comment: Thanks @Vineeth. but another question is: I found 'marvel.agent.enabled: false' for disabling logging. but I think it's not working at all. if I want to stop logging which one is a good way: setting MaxFileSize to 0 or disabling marvel.agent ?

Comment: and if its possible please introduce me a good source for elasticsearch administration studying. I read 'elasticsearch server' but it not include content such as my question :)

Comment: You can use TTL - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-ttl-field.html

Comment: thank you @Vineeth and I'm sorry for asking many questions. I mean which book you recommend me to study about elasticsearch administration? or any document which describes contents such as logging or any other administration tasks.